# How to set x Axis label values in Windows Forms

Tags: c#, winforms

So I am working on a Project in Windows Forms where I need to display  datas on Diagram. I have 6 Points and I have successfully added them on Diagramm. So everything is working fine but I need to change X Axis label Values. I have setted minimum value to 0 and maximum to 100 000, interval 10 000 but I need to display on X Axes following Values: 330, 4700, 50000, 12 200, 25 570, 100 000. But wenn I am setting Interval(20 000) it display something like this: 0, 20 000, 40 000.. 100 000. How can I do this ?

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to have the points at  x-positions proportional to the x-values you can set the `Series` to display the x-values as **indexed**. Then they will all sit at the same intervals:

```
yourSeries.IsXValueIndexed = true;
```

With these data:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
         yourSeries.Points.AddXY(i*i, i + 10 * Math.Sin(i/12f));
```

these are the results, before:

[image]

..and after:

[image]

You can use the `Interval` property of various axes properties to style the display. The make the labels display something completly different or at some other, not automatically calculated positions you will need to use `CustomLabels`..

Comment: nope. i want to display between intervals definition of a Point x Coordiantes. For example x(20, 50) and interval is: 0 50 100 150... and I want to display between 0 and 50 x-coordinate(20)

Comment: Well, that is not what you asked for is it? It calls for CustomLabels then, as I wrote in the answer.